# Converting result of MySql Query to Array

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, arrays

I am getting RowPacketData after executing a query, now I want to convert that RowPacketData to an array so that I can perform different operations on it.

```
var query = `Select products.*, product_images.Image_Name 
from products INNER JOIN product_images 
ON products.Id=product_images.Product_Id ORDER BY Id limit ${LimitNum} OFFSET ${startNum}`;
db.query(query , function(err,rows, fields)
{
  if (err) 
  {
    res.status(500).send({ error: 'Following Error Occured : '+ err });
    console.log('Following Error Occured : ' + err);
  }
  else
  {      
    res.json(rows);
    console.log('20 Products Displayed on Page : ' + page);    
  }
})
```

Note : I am using node js.

Comment: now i want to convert the rows variable to an array.

Comment: yes for query on multiple lines and using variable in the query.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Try `res.json(JSON.stringify(rows));`

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with your db connection. You should add a check for the db connection before you do the query.

See here for example:
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql_select.asp

Your query and code looks correct. Start with a simpler query and expand it slowly(This will detect error in query) and also make the connection at same place with error handling. To 100% sure you have a connection.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("Select * from products limit", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

PS: I can not make comment so needed to write an attempt on answer directly. However should be good to know if you are sure you have a connection, so that can be  taken out of the problem equation.